# Animating SVG anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to do a simple svg animation, where a menu link has an svg underline, I'd like to animate the line to create a very simple shape. Basically a single line made of total 7 anchors where the middle 3 anchors (each ofsetting by 2) would be moved on the Y-axis a couple pixels to top.

E.g. from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Is this possible? Do I need to use an svg animation framework or is there a simpler way to do this?

Or should I use sprint and animate positioning of the spring svg canvas?

I'll be happy for any help, Thank you.

Comment: have you tried something? could you share some code?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a framework for such simple animation, but I'm not sure what are other options at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are actually after. Your description is not clear.  Did you mean something like this?

```css
svg {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #212121;
}

path {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #79b;
   stroke-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 260 100">
  <path d="M0,0">
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML"
       from="M10,75l40,0l40,0l40,0l40,0l40,0l40,0;"
       to="M10,75l40,-50l40,50l40,-50l40,50l40,-50l40,50"
       dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, I'm sorry that I've kept this unupdated, I have updated the code from fcalderan to suit my case, this is very close to what I've used eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably as little closer to what you initially asked for:

```js
$('a').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.animIn')[0].beginElement();
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.animOut')[0].beginElement();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

polyline {
  stroke: #48B4D3;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #48B4D3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Some link
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="62px" height="12px" viewBox="0 0 62 12">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="61,10.5 51,10.5 41,10.5 31,10.5 21,10.5 11,10.5 1,10.5 ">
      <animate class="animIn" begin="indefinite" attributeName="points" dur="200ms" fill="freeze" to="61,11 51,5 41,11 31,5 21,11 11,5 1,11" />
      <animate class="animOut" begin="indefinite" attributeName="points" dur="200ms" fill="freeze" to="61,10.5 51,10.5 41,10.5 31,10.5 21,10.5 11,10.5 1,10.5" />
    </polyline>
  </svg>
</a>

<a href="#">Another link
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="62px" height="12px" viewBox="0 0 62 12">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="61,10.5 51,10.5 41,10.5 31,10.5 21,10.5 11,10.5 1,10.5 ">
      <animate class="animIn" begin="indefinite" attributeName="points" dur="200ms" fill="freeze" to="61,11 51,5 41,11 31,5 21,11 11,5 1,11" />
      <animate class="animOut" begin="indefinite" attributeName="points" dur="200ms" fill="freeze" to="61,10.5 51,10.5 41,10.5 31,10.5 21,10.5 11,10.5 1,10.5" />
    </polyline>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution, I've ended up using something similar to the one below however, this is exactly the kind of animation I was looking for.

Sorry for keeping this unupdated in the meanwhile..